# rtl8812au wireless driver installation on Centos 7

Tags: centos, wifi, drivers, make

I have a fresh install of Cent OS 7 with the Gnome desktop environment. I have been trying to install rtl8812au wireless drivers found at https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au for my Netgear A6100 WiFi USB Mini Adapter and run into the following error:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/build M=/home/testuser/Downloads/rtl8812au-master  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Trying to find a solution to the problem, I performed a `sudo yum update` and a `sudo yum install kernel-devel` but still does not seem to fix the problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The missing file should be a symlink to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64`. The latter should have been installed by the `kernel-devel` package. Confirm that the symlink is valid.

Comment: The symlink from `/lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/build` to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64` is confirmed valid

Comment: Therefore `ls /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/build` (as the same user used to compile above) shows various directories and files? How odd!

Comment: actually a `ls /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/build` outputs `No such file or Directory` but a `ls -ltr /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64` shows the symlink of the `build` directory to point to `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64`

Comment: If `ls /lib/...` shows no files or directory then you probably have the wrong version of `kernel-devel` installed. Did you reboot after `yum update`? You can force the correct version with `yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-123.el7`. You can see what you have installed with `yum list installed kernel-devel`.

Comment: Actually the reboot did the trick. After a `yum install kernel-devel`, I might have forgotten to reboot. Thanks for all the help with debugging the issue.